# Update package installation throwing XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: update-packages

I'm trying to upgrade an 8.1 install to 8.2. I've followed the steps in the guide so far, including installing the UpgradeInstallationWizard package.

When I select the .update package and try to progress to the next step I get this unhelpful error message,

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://<mysite>/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx?page=1
Line Number 1, Column 1:
^
```

The sitecore logs aren't giving me any information on what the problem is. Where can I look to find out why the upgrade installation wizard isn't happy with the .update package I'm trying to install?

Comment: Try to rename the package from .update to .zip and open the package to see if the items and files are present in it

Comment: The contents of the .update are 4 more .updates.
Sitecore 8.2 rev. 160729 (update package).zip contains Sitecore 8.2 rev. 160729.update.
Sitecore 8.2 rev. 160729.update contains Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003.update, Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207, Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160302.update, Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160519.update

Those smaller .update files contain package.zips with items inside.

Comment: I didn't quite get your comment

Comment: Heh I'm saying the .update package for 8.2, when renamed to .zip, contains 4 more .update files. Those files contain package.zips with items.

Comment: If you extract the main .update package and try to install the .update in the main one, does it work?

Comment: I've forgot to mention, you will need to install it in the correct order

Comment: So extracting and installing the individual .updates from the larger .update file seems to be working. I'm assuming the update to the installation wizard is to support the nested .update format, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, i will put it as answer so that it may help others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the .update package can be converted to a zip file. You just need to rename the .update to .zip.

Once this is done, open the package and see if the items and dlls are present in the sub folders. If you have more .update package inside the package, you can try to unzip the main .update package and the install the sub .update package individually.

If you have errors while installing one of the .update package, it means that this .update package may contain corrupt items.